# Cannot connect to a Postgres SQL instance from inside a pod within a GKE

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Terraform and Google Cloud.

I am trying to create a K8 cluster where pods inside the cluster could communicate with a Postgres server I have within the same VPC.

However, when I try to connect to the server using a `psql` client within a ubuntu pod inside the cluster using `psql -h <PRIVATE_IP_OF_POSTGRES_SERVER> -U postgresadmin`, it waits for a long time and throws the following timeout error.

```sh
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "<PRIVATE_IP_OF_POSTGRES_SERVER>" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I even tried to `telnet <PRIVATE_IP_OF_POSTGRES_SERVER>` and that is also not working. (PING is not working as well)

Here is my terraform script for creating the VPC and the K8 cluster:

```yaml
variable "project_id" {
  description = "project id"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "region"
}

variable "gke_username" {
  default     = ""
  description = "gke username"
}

variable "gke_password" {
  default     = ""
  description = "gke password"
}

variable "gke_num_nodes" {
  default     = 1
  description = "number of gke nodes"
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

# VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name                    = "${var.project_id}-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

# Subnet
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  name          = "${var.project_id}-subnet"
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  ip_cidr_range = "10.10.0.0/24"
}

# GKE cluster
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-gke"
  location = var.region

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  network    = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name

  # Create a VPC-native cluster by configuring `ip_allocation_policy` 
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_ipv4_cidr_block  = "/16"
    services_ipv4_cidr_block = "/22"
  }

  master_auth {
    username = var.gke_username
    password = var.gke_password

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
}

# Separately Managed Node Pool
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {
  name       = "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}-node-pool"
  location   = var.region
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = var.gke_num_nodes

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    labels = {
      env = var.project_id
    }

    # preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
    tags         = ["gke-node", "${var.project_id}-gke"]
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my terraform script file for creating the Postgres server:

```yaml
variable "project_id" {
  description = "project id"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "region"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.61.0"
    }
  }
}

data "google_compute_network" "my_network" {
  name = "novade-lite-vpc"
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

resource "random_id" "db_name_suffix" {
  byte_length = 4
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = data.google_compute_network.my_network.self_link
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  network                 = data.google_compute_network.my_network.self_link
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
  name             = "postgres-instance-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      private_network = data.google_compute_network.my_network.self_link
    }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "default" {
  name       = "default"
  project    = var.project_id
  instance   = google_sql_database_instance.postgres.name
  collation  = "en_US.UTF8"
  depends_on = [google_sql_database_instance.postgres]
}

resource "google_sql_user" "users" {
  name     = "postgresadmin"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.postgres.name
  password = "password"
  depends_on = [google_sql_database_instance.postgres]
}
```

Here is my variables file (Same for both the above scripts):

```yaml
project_id = "test-project"
region     = "europe-west2"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Eranga, There are a couple of ways in which you can connect to an SQL instance outside the GKE cluster. The preferred way to consume other GCP products from GKE is to use `Workload Identity`. Have a look at the available options here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Shabirmean. I saw this document but frankly, it seemed a little advance for me at this stage. I saw [this article](https://medium.com/@johnjjung/how-to-setup-a-kubernetes-cluster-that-can-connect-to-sql-on-gcp-using-private-ips-c0cd41ea3a4e) of someone who does the same thing for a MySQL server but not using Terraform. I'm just trying to understand whether I need to do something specifically for allowing access to the server from inside pods or whether there is a mistake in my current script. :-)

Comment: Further, another problem I face with this article is that I have to do a lot of manual stuff using cloud shell whereas I would want this to be handled by Terraform. If you can provide a terraform example of achieving what I need, that would be marvelous. 

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of how GKE setup works but I can give u some pointers based on my understanding of similar setup in AWS.

Your cluster pod will be one on of the NODES, this node will be part of some subnet and also will have some security group (type of firewall) attached to it.

Similarly postgres DB is created in some subnet and security group attached to it.

Now make sure that the DB security group all inbound traffic on 5432 port from pods subnet range or from security group.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I managed to fix the issue and I will put the answer when I have time.

Comment: @ErangaHeshanhow do you remember how you managed to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a non RFC1918 network range for pods. `5.0.0.0/16`

After updating the network range to something like `10.33.0.0/16`, I was able to connect.

More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/unable-to-connect-to-cloud-sql-via-private-ip-from-a-gke-cluster-000007945)

Answer (score 0):

To enable communication between your GKE cluster and `Cloud SQL` `PostgreSQL`, both resources must reside in the same `VPC`. Ensure that you are using the same `VPC` for both `GKE` and `Cloud SQL` in your Terraform configurations.

If the issue persists, verify the `firewall rules` for your GKE cluster. Create a firewall rule allowing traffic on port `5432` (PostgreSQL default port) from the GKE instances to the Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance. The source range in the firewall rule should include the IP addresses of your instances.

Here is the revised version of your Terraform code:

## main.tf - Configuration for GKE Cluster

```
variable "project_id" {
  description = "project id"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "region"
}

variable "gke_username" {
  default     = ""
  description = "gke username"
}

variable "gke_password" {
  default     = ""
  description = "gke password"
}

variable "gke_num_nodes" {
  default     = 1
  description = "number of gke nodes"
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

# VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name                    = "${var.project_id}-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

# Subnet
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  name          = "${var.project_id}-subnet"
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  ip_cidr_range = "10.10.0.0/24"
}

# GKE cluster
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "${var.project_id}-gke"
  location = var.region

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  network    = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name

  # Create a VPC-native cluster by configuring `ip_allocation_policy` 
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_ipv4_cidr_block  = "/16"
    services_ipv4_cidr_block = "/22"
  }

  master_auth {
    username = var.gke_username
    password = var.gke_password

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
}

# main.tf - Configuration for SQL Database Instance

data "google_compute_network" "my_network" {
  name = google_compute_network.vpc.name  # Use the same VPC as in the GKE configuration
}

resource "random_id" "db_name_suffix" {
  byte_length = 4
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = data.google_compute_network.my_network.self_link
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  network                 = data.google_compute_network.my_network.self_link
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
  name             = "postgres-instance-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  depends_on       = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
  }
}
```